# How to recognize and decode encoded string

Tags: encryption, encoding

I writing an application that using http request for authentication. Because of security matter, I am using WireShark to sniff the http packet to see if can steal the username and password.

When using WireShark, I got this encoded string:

```
TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAHIAAADcANwAigAAAAQABABYAAAAEgASAFwAAAAEAAQAbgAAABAAEABmAQAAFYKI4gYDgCUAAAAP255D/F478qJlQoJwEti1LGgAcABzAGwAZQBlAGsAYgBvAG8AawBIAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGao0slMmaggkTP6jJJHJUwEBAAAAAAAABaWp/E9p0QGDaAQ319vuYgAAAAACAAQASABQAAEABABIAFAABAAEAGgAcAADAAQAaABwAAcACAAFpan8T2nRAQYABAACAAAACAAwADAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAgAAAkOEBAmC7E+a9Pa8Y4gF0J9zeqVTsT7BCXKEhznVGMpwoAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACQAkAEgAVABUAFAALwAxADkAMgAuADEANgA4AC4AMQAuADEAMQAzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFq8ggyPeAnfXnSiV12/Z1Y=
```

I do research online, and I guess this is Base64 encoded. Then, I tried to decode from this website:

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/

I managed to see my username which is sleekbook, but the others still seems unknown to me. Is it because it's not Base64 encoding or it's further encrypted by some other algo as well?

Comment: If you managed to decrypt/decode the string and got a valid result (your username), it is unlikely that you picked the wrong encryption/encoding. I would imagine that other information is either further encoded, or a different data format.

Comment: Ok, noted! Thanks pal. Just curious if you can decode that, please do let me know! :))